# Getting ubi-partman failed with exit code 10 when trying to install Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a hard drive. I started of by going into *Try Ubuntu* and after that tried to install it. I got through the set-up process, but then it crashed. When I tried to redo it, I got this error:

[image]

If I go into syslog it gives me this:

```
ubi-partman failed with exit code 10. 
Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog.
```

[image]

Comment: I also have this issue. I've tried re-doing the entire installation but I get the same error. Any luck finding a solution?